# How can I save data from a html form in a file?

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I did the simple form.In that i am trying modifying the $_post output.

```
<?php

    $lhs = array();
    $rhs = array();

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . "=" . $value;
        echo "<br>";
        $lhs[] = $key; //first array for left hand side 
        $rhs[] = $value; //second array for right hand side

    }

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Phone No: <input type="text" name="phone" /><br/>
    Course:<input type="text" name="course" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

So the output of this could be:

```
name=xyz
phone=123455453
course=be
Submit=Sign Up
```

now you can observe see that I am getting the output of the button also:

```
Submit=Sign Up
```

Which I don't require in the output. And I require the output something like this:

```
name=xyz
phone=123455453
course=be
```

This output I want to store in a text file.

I am not able to modify the output either I am not able to store this output in a text file.

How can I get rid of the submit button output and save the data into a file?

Any Help or advice is appreciated and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look to [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: you could just take `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['phone']` and `$_POST['course']` without taking the worthless button input.

Comment: why dont you try with array_pop(); which remove the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I first added a if statement to check if your submit button was pressed with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and all fields aren't [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

In the foreach loop I simply added an if statement to check if the current key is the submit button and if yes I just skip the iteration with [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

To now save the data into a file I used [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) where I then go through both arrays with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return the key/value pair as combined elements with a new line character ([`PHP_EOL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)) at the end of each element.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST["Submit"]) && !empty($_POST["name"]) && !empty($_POST["phone"]) && !empty($_POST["course"])) {

        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key == "Submit") continue;
            echo $lhs[] = $key; //first array for left hand side 
            echo $rhs[] = $value; //second array for right hand side
        }

        file_put_contents("file.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, array_map(function($v1, $v2){
            return "$v1:$v2";
        }, $lhs, $rhs)), FILE_APPEND);

    }

?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Phone No: <input type="text" name="phone" /><br/>
    Course:<input type="text" name="course" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot man..but in the text file i am getting this text "SubmitSign"..which i dont want

Comment: @Awanti Are you sure you copied my full code and the submit button name is: `Submit` ? You need the if statement to check for the submit button in the foreach loop!

Comment: is it possible to remove tat???

Comment: another way would be just to omit the name attribute on the submit button, you're guaranteed you'll never have that index inside POST

Comment: @Ghost Yeah would also work, you also would have to remove the check with isset for the submit button

Comment: @Rizier123 right, the OP would need to change that too accordingly, a little bit overkill on the `array_map` lol :D but should work just fine.

Comment: @Awanti So were are we with the question? Did it worked?

Comment: no it is not working...but i am trying every modification on submit

Comment: @Awanti Please post a http://pastebin.com/ link from your **entire** code. How you used it right now!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8aNJ4RCp

Comment: @Awanti ^ You don't have the if statement to check if the submit button is pressed! Copy my **full** code from my answer again and try it, it should work

Comment: hey it worked....million thousand thanx to u...u saved me...!!!

Comment: hey one little favor??if u dont mind

Comment: @Awanti And that would be?

Comment: i want to overwrite the file instead of appending

Comment: @Awanti Remove this part: `, FILE_APPEND` from the `file_put_contents()` call! That's it.

Comment: it works like a charm now...thanku once again

Answer (score 0):

You can access each variable by input name, as follows:

```
<?php
  echo "Name = " . $_POST["name"];
  echo "Phone = " . $_POST["phone"];
  echo "Course = " . $_POST["course"];
?>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Phone No: <input type="text" name="phone" /><b>
    Course:<input type="text" name="course" /> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change your html to be:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
```

Removing the `name` attribute, will prevent it from showing up in $_POST

Or you can just unset the value:

```
unset($_POST['Submit']);
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){...
```

Which will unset it from the `$_POST` array

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$file = fopen("test.txt", "w");
$file_contents = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    $file_contents .= $key ."=". $value.'\n' ;

fwrite($file, $file_contents);
fclose($file);
```